# worker inside define module is uploaded using absolute path instead of a relative, why?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, web-worker

I have the following module:

```
define('jsViz',['require','jquery'],function (require) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
        src = scripts[scripts.length-1].src,
        dotWorker = new Worker("/JSViz/main.js?v=2");
});
```

`scripts[scripts.length-1].src` returns `domain/dist/js/index.js` which is the URL of currently executing script. Worker constructor accepts relative path to the currently executing script, so when I specify `/JSViz/main.js` I assume the script will be loaded from `domain/dist/js/JSViz/main.js`, however the browser tries to load script from `domain/JSViz/main.js`. Why so?

PS. The module definition is from r.js optimization output that's why the module is named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

> When the Worker(scriptURL) constructor is invoked, the user agent must
>   run the following steps:
>
> Resolve the scriptURL argument relative to the entry script's base
>   URL, when the method is invoked.